# running Protractor on headless FF from jenkins with xvfb

Tags: firefox, jenkins, protractor, headless, xvfb

Can't get my protractor running on remote server on headless mode. I'll be glad if anyone could help

- This is my qa server setting:

Under `/etc/init.d/xvfb` script to `stat Xvfb :99`

`export DISPLAY=:99` set in bash_profile ( `echo $DISPLAY` returns `:99`)

firefox and protractor installed.

- My project `pom.xml`:

I'm using maven-wagon-plugin to execute

1. The script starting xvfb on display:99 on my qa server
2. Run protractor `protractorTest/conf.js` on my qa server

When running the job from jenkins

> => I'm getting error  E/launcher - Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.
>
> Firefox console output: Error: no display specified

Checked if the `xvfb` is running:

`ps -ef | grep Xvfb` on QA server shows the Xvfb process running, but

Please let me know if something is wrong or missing?

Comment: Try running your protractor test using `xvfb-run`. Try the below command in terminal. `xvfb-run protractorTest/conf.js`

Comment: thank you, I found out why it was not working. I had to start the xvfb in the same script that is running protractor. I used maven wagon plugin to execute the command that starts the xvfb + runs protractor tests

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in running cucumber-jvm selenium test cases in headless mode under jenkins build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511124/error-in-running-cucumber-jvm-selenium-test-cases-in-headless-mode-under-jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

The `xvfb` need to start in the same script that is running protractor. So Maven wagon plugin can be used to execute the command that starts the `xvfb` + runs protractor tests.

<sup>Source: [@sou](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39976721/running-protractor-on-headless-ff-from-jenkins-with-xvfb#comment68022000_39976721) comment.</sup>